# How to read aws sam parameter in .NET lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, sam

I have a SAM template that takes parameters in the .yml file, and I want to access the parameter value within the lambda function written in c#

here is the SAM template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >      
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60
    Runtime: dotnetcore2.1
Parameters: 
  ApiBaseUri: 
    Type: String
    Default: https://postb.in/1584332032935-8906962152104
    Description: The API URL where the received events will be pushed by the lambda function
Resources:
  PushUpdates:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src/PushAPIs/
      Handler: Localgov.Microservices::LambPaymentTracker.UpdateHandler::PushBurtonUpdates
      Runtime: dotnetcore2.1
      Policies: AWSLambdaDynamoDBExecutionRole
      Events:
        Stream:
          Type: DynamoDB
          Properties:
            Stream: !GetAtt UpdatesTable.StreamArn
            BatchSize: 100
            StartingPosition: TRIM_HORIZON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way of passing cloudformation (or sam) variables to lambda would be through [Environment Variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html).

In your template you specify the variables using [Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-environment) property.

In your code, you then use your programming language specific functionality to read them.

Comment: thanks @Marcin what is the diff between parameter and environment variables?

Comment: @طارقالشيخورق `Parameters` is section of your template, which you can't access in your lambda function. `environment variable` will be accessible from lambda.